# Pass by reference swift class issue

Tags: swift

i am somewhat new to swift and still trying to get a grasp on the knowledge. which is probably why i've run into waht feels like a simple mistake. i know that class instances are reference types but even knowing that im not entirely sure how to get the result im after. i want to change my SHIPTO without modifying my BILLTO. does anyone know a fix for this?

```
class Home {
    var house: String
    var street: String
    var postalCode: String
    
    init(house: String, street: String, postalCode: String) {
        self.house = house
        self.street = street
        self.postalCode = postalCode
    }
}
class DeliveryAdress {
    var orderNumber: Int
    var Shipto: Home
    var Billto: Home

    init(orderNumber: Int, Shipto: Home, Billto: Home) {
        self.orderNumber = orderNumber
        self.Shipto = Shipto
        self.Billto = Billto
    }
}

var homeAddress = Home(house: "appartment style", street: "Pizza Pie Road", postalCode: "90210")

var pizzaDelivery = DeliveryAdress(orderNumber: 001, Shipto: homeAddress, Billto: homeAddress)

pizzaDelivery.Shipto.street = "123 Street"

print(pizzaDelivery.Billto.street)

// this should NOT print "123 street"

print(pizzaDelivery.Shipto.street)

// this SHOULD print 123 street
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 solutions:

1. Use value types - change `class` to `struct`
2. Create separate `Home` instances for `shipTo` and `billTo`

I'd suggest sticking with `struct`s, since unless you explicitly need reference-type behaviour, you should always prefer structs over classes in Swift.

```
struct Home {
    var house: String
    var street: String
    var postalCode: String
}

struct DeliveryAddress {
    var orderNumber: Int
    var shipTo: Home
    var billTo: Home
}

var homeAddress = Home(house: "appartment style", street: "Pizza Pie Road", postalCode: "90210")

var pizzaDelivery = DeliveryAddress(orderNumber: 001, shipTo: homeAddress, billTo: homeAddress)

pizzaDelivery.shipTo.street = "123 Street"

print(pizzaDelivery.billTo.street)
print(pizzaDelivery.shipTo.street)
```

There are a couple of general issues with your code:

- The Swift naming convention is lowerCamelCase for variable+function names, and UpperCamelCase for type names. So `shipTo` and `billTo`, not `Shipto`.
- By default, everything should be immutable, only use mutable properties when you really need them to be mutable.
- Use `struct` instead of `class` unless you explicitly need reference-type behaviour.

Comment: You could also implement the copy method in your Home class, and install a copy of the shipTo address in the billTo address. See this link for a discussion of using `copy(with:)`: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-copy-objects-in-swift-using-copy

Answer (score 1):

As you said `classes` are reference type so the property of `street` has an adress lets say `"A"`. `pizzaDelivery.Shipto.street` and `pizzaDelivery.billTo.street` refers to same address , its `A`. If you change `pizzaDelivery.billTo.street` this value .Its actually changing value which address is `A` . So In that situations You need to use `Struct`. If you change Home type yo Struct , issue gonna be fixed

```
struct Home {
var house: String
var street: String
var postalCode: String
}
```